# Как отложить выполнение следующей сallback функции?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

У меня есть обработчик событий, который при отлавливании определенного тега в xml вызывает обратную функцию.
В обратной функции я выполняю операции сложения и сравнения , затем записываю данные в MongoDB с помощью Mongoose.
Обработчик в мгновение срабатывает 10 раз и, соответственно вызывает 10 функций.
В консоле я наблюдаю, что сначала выполняются "операции сложения и сравнения", для каждой вызванной функции, а только затем идет 10 подряд записей в MongoDB.
Как мне задержать исполнение следующий сallback-функций, пока не воспроизведется запись в Mongo, т.е пока не выполнится весь необходимый код в первом сallback?

Пример кода:

```
    xmlStream.on('tag:offer', async function (offer) {
        let difference = offer.oldprice - offer.price;
        console.log(difference);
        if (difference > 0){
            await Raw_data.create({price: +offer.price});
        }
    })
```

[image: Сначала вывод ВСЕХ difference, а затем уже запись всех документов в базу]

Comment: запустите метод, в коллбэке или промисе  метода записи

Comment: @Дмытрык, так он и так сейчас в колбеке.

Comment: Попробуйте создать глобальную переменную isLoading = false; и в теле синхронной функции переназначать её в true, а когда получен результат из await Raw_data.create({price: +offer.price}) сделать проверку и перезаписать переменную опять на false. Начинать выполнение коллбэка только при значении переменной false

Comment: А вообще, вы желаете чтобы асинхронный код выполнялся синхронно, есть возможность это сделать лишь блокируя всё приложение - те же лоадеры на сайтах. Смысл асинхронности в ускорении работы приложения посмотрите хотя-бы на Youtube, вы же не ждёте, пока все остальные оставят комментарий. Есть лишь два пути: отобразить устаревшую информацию до окончания выполнения асинхронного кода (обновления компонента) или блокировать всё приложение (в случае больших приложений - недопустимо)

Comment: Alexander P, а в случае написания парсера?) В общем буду записывать данные колбеков во внешний объект, в очередь и потом по очереди их исполнять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю суть, тут может быть несколько вариантов:

- вы должны управлять xml потоком, т.е. получили тэг, поставили поток на паузу, обработали, пошли дальше.
- данные которые вы обрабатываете, попробуйте отдавать в следующий поток. А в нём по мере поступления данных либо складывайте в очередь, либо сразу вставляйте в монгу. Тут вы точно можете управлять потоком. Нужно , чтобы xmlstream был transform stream и можно было управлять передачей данных.
- можете создать кэш и складывать туда все данные для вставки. А после завершения потока вставить сразу все вместе.

Comment: да, я ставлю поток на паузу во время того когда вызывается первый кол бек, но все равно успевает проскочить порядка 10-40 тегов и вызываются другие колбеки.
Спасибо за совет! Только не очень понятно как реализовать 2-ой вариант

Comment: А если складывать в очередь(объект) нужные данные, а потом уже их потоком обработать, то это не скажется негативно на ресурсах? Допустим если xml пол гига?

Comment: Скажется, именно поэтому нужно обрабатывать данные по мере поступления. Во втором варике вставка происходит внутри Writable или Transform stream. Во Writable переопределяете _write, там делаете работу по вставки и т.д.